# Having trouble making multiple directories and files

Tags: command-line

I am taking an intro Linux class this semester. I just totally bombed the midterm hands. I couldn't get my commands to work. I am posting what I entered. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong as my instructor is no help whatsoever.

```
Mkdir –p ~/midterm/linux/{desktops/{GNOME,KDE,LXDE,Xfce},distros/,players/{Andrew\ Tanenbaum,Linus\ Torvald,Richard\ Stallman}}
```

Comment: well what error did you get? Did you really enter `Mkdir` with a capital M?

Comment: It said none of the files or directories exist

Answer (score 1):

This creates a `midterm` directory in your home directory (denoted by the `~`) with a bunch of other directories under it.

> It said none of the files or directories exist

Your `mkdir` should have a lowercase `m` and your `-p` is incorrect because it is not using a dash; possibly because it was copied from, for example, a PDF file. After copying the command to the command line, replace the `Mkdir` by `mkdir`, and replace `–p` by `-p`.

Final result:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/midterm/linux/{desktops/{GNOME,KDE,LXDE,Xfce},distros/,players/{Andrew\ Tanenbaum,Linus\ Torvald,Richard\ Stallman}}
$ tree ~/midterm/
/home/daniel/midterm/
└── linux
    ├── desktops
    │   ├── GNOME
    │   ├── KDE
    │   ├── LXDE
    │   └── Xfce
    ├── distros
    └── players
        ├── Andrew Tanenbaum
        ├── Linus Torvald
        └── Richard Stallman

11 directories, 0 files
```

The `\` (followed by a space) is used to escape spaces in directory names.

Comment: I think I get it but, I'm still not sure. How do you copy and paste stuff into CLI? I've never touched Linux before this semester began and the instructor teaches like we should know it and it is obvious I don't.

Comment: "How do you copy and paste stuff into CLI?" --- (1) Use the mouse with right-click copy and then right-click paste, or (2) use the keyboard with ctrl+c to copy and ctrl+shift+v to paste into the terminal. Afterwards, you have to fix the incorrect parts: the `mkdir` and the `-p`. Another approach is to first copy the full command to, for example, `gedit` (text editor in Ubuntu), fix the command there, and then copy the correct command to the terminal.